# passport.authenticate - username and password are null

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

this is probably some basic mistake but I am watching tutorial and even though I think I done everything exactly like I should after submitting login form I am redirected to the "failureRedirect" page. When I looked at source code in passport module I something.

After this:

```
Strategy.prototype.authenticate = function(req, options) {

  options = options || {};

  var username = lookup(req.body, this._usernameField) || lookup(req.query, this._usernameField);

  var password = lookup(req.body, this._passwordField) || lookup(req.query, this._passwordField);

  //I added:
  console.log("U-> " + username);
  console.log("P-> " + password);
```

console says

```
U-> null

P-> null
```

Then after this, rest is not executed.

```
 if (!username || !password) {
     return this.fail({ message: options.badRequestMessage || 'Missing credentials' }, 400);
   }
```

I am not sure which parts of code should I post here. Maybe this can help

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done){
    console.log("passport.use new LocalStrategy");  //never gets executed
```

***//never gets executed***

```
    User.getUserByUsername(username, function(err, user){
      if (err) throw err;
      if(!user) {
        console.log("Unknown user");
        return done(null, false, {message: "Uknkown User"});
    }
    User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch){
      if (err) throw err;
      if (isMatch) {
        return done(null, user);
      } else { 
        console.log("invalid Pass");
        return done(null, false, {message: "Invalid Password"});
   }
  });
 });
}));

router.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", {failureRedirect:"/users/login/err", failureFlash:"invalid username or pass"}), function(req, res){
  console.log("Authenticated OK");
  req.flash("success", "You are logged in");
  res.redirect("/xx");
});
```

Comment: Have you set up the [Passport middleware](http://passportjs.org/docs/configure) properly?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the exact implementation that you are doing. Probably you are overriding the authenticate functionality using the prototype pattern. 
However, Authentication using Passportjs is simple. I have done one recently in my side project. Please go through the below link with my own experience on implementing Passportjs
 [I have a well documented artcile that i wrote on my tech blog. Hope this helps you](http://eshwartechtalks.blogspot.in/2015/07/nodejs-rest-api-authentication-using.html)

```
// complete code for the exmaple node rest api authentication using passport
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
var passportHttp = require('passport-http');
var basicStrategy = passportHttp.BasicStrategy; // using the basic     authentication

var app = express();

app.get('/',function(req,res){
res.send("There you go");
});

app.use(passport.initialize()); // initialize and use it in express

passport.use(new passportHttp.BasicStrategy(function(username,password,done)        {
    if(username === password){
    done(null,username); //null means no error and return is the username
}
else{
    return done(null,'there is no entry for you!'); // null means nothing to say,
    //no error. 2nd is the custom statement business rule
    }
}));
// this function hits first when there is an API call. 
function ensureAuthenticated(req,res,next){
if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        next(); 
    // next redirects the user to the next api function waiting to be executed in the express framework
}else{
    res.sendStatus(403); //forbidden || unauthorized
}
};
// this means all the API calls that hit via mydomain.com/api/ uses this  authentication.
//session is false, because its a HTTP API call.
// setting this helps passport to skip the check if its an API call or a session web call
app.use('/api',passport.authenticate('basic',{session:false})); 
// this is served the user once the authentication is a susccess
app.get('/api/data',ensureAuthenticated,function(req,res){
var somevalue = [{name: 'foo'},
    {name: 'bar'},
    {name: 'baz'}];
    res.send(somevalue);
});

app.listen(3250);
console.log('listening to port on ' + 3250);
```